# Change Camera pixel format from qml

Tags: qt, camera, qml, qtmultimedia, qcamera

Looking at the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcameraviewfindersettings.html#details) of Qt5 it seems possible to change the pixel format of the camera. I need to create a `QCameraViewfinderSettings` set the new pixel format and set the new settings to the camera... like in this example

```
QCameraViewfinderSettings viewfinderSettings;
viewfinderSettings.setPixelFormat(QVideoFrame::Format_RGB32);
camera->setViewfinderSettings(viewfinderSettings);
```

But I cannot find anything similar in QML... Is there any way to do the something in QML? I'd like something like:

```
Camera {
    id: camera
    viewfinder.pixelFormat = VideoFrame.Format_RGB32
}
```

If QML doesn't allow me to set the pixel format what alternatives have I?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't change the pixel format in QML [per the maintainer of that component](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42909), but you can pass the QML object to C++ and do it from there [per bug report  42909](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42909).

As Yoann Lopes wrote in that bug's comments, you can access the QCamera of the QML object with:

```
QCamera *cam = qvariant_cast<QCamera*>(obj->property("mediaObject"))
```